# Confuse about service provider in spring security saml

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, saml

I am learning how to implement single sign on by using spring security saml for my school assignment. I want to implement SSO function that when I login to one application, there is no need to login to other applications. I have walked through the quick start example and read through the whole document. But still have no clue how to map a spring service provider to several different applications. DO I need to configure each web application as an individual service provider? Or create one web application acting as the only service provider then map it to several applications? Any help will be so grateful.

Comment: I created two applications by using the quick start sample with different entity_sp.xml and only the single sign on take effect. When logout happened in one application, ssocircle account did logout. However, another application did not logout. When application 1 logged out. There was an exception occurring in application 2, saying "LogoutRequest is required to be signed by the entity policy". Any wrong thing I have done?

Comment: In both the ExtendedMetaData, I set "requireLogoutRequestSigned" to be false and single logout works. So who should sign the logout request? I think it should be IDP but how to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security SAML extention implements the Service Provider part of SAMLv2. The SP is not in charge for authentication. This happens on the Identity Provider side. When dealing with SAML you may first read the tech overview at http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/27819/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.pdf, to get an idea about the technology.